# Spring HATEOAS error handling with VndErrors

Tags: java, spring, hateoas

I am struggling to find a clean way of handling errors produced by an HATEOAS enabled api.

Basically our backend service is a spring application that in case of exceptions uses  `@ControllerAdvice` to return a `VndErrors` instance back to the consumer.

`VndErrors` is provided by `spring-hateoas` and once returned will be serialised and marked as `application/vnd.error`.

On the service consumer part we are also using `spring-hateoas` and we communicate with the backend service via a standard `RestTemplate`.

The default `ResponseErrorHandler` in the `RestTemplate` throws exceptions for client, server or uknown http statues responses but it doesn't attempt to deserialise the response body in anyway.

```
public MyBusinessConcept myBusinessConcept() {
    try {
        return restTemplate().exchange("http://foo/bar",  ..., MyBusinessConcept.class).getBody();
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
        // ???
    }
}
```

How can we get back the `VndErrors` instance from a failed http response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of researches I happen to find an answer within some other spring [module](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/blob/master/spring-cloud-dataflow-rest-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/dataflow/rest/client/VndErrorResponseErrorHandler.java).

Basically a solution is to implement the `ResponseErrorHandler` interface, either using inheritance or composition (better) to fallback to the `DefaultResponseErrorHandler`. The implementation would use a `ResponseExtractor<VndErrors>` to deserialise our errors back.